# Writing own repeat function in Haskell: getting error C stack overflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

When I'm trying to write repeat in Haskell, the ERROR - C stack overflow pop up.

```
repeat' :: a -> [a]
repeat' a = repeat' a ++ [a]
```

And I'm aware that the right way is to do:

```
repeat' :: a -> [a]
repeat' a = a: repeat' a
```

But still want to ask why it happens, is there something wrong with the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that an expression like `repeat' 3` will 
be evaluated like this

```
repeat' 3 ++ [3]
repeat' 3 ++ [3] ++ [3]
repeat' 3 ++ [3] ++ [3] ++ [3]
```

leading to a blowup of stack space. The reason why it is evaluated
like that is because of the precedence. Function application has the
highest precedence and hence it is evaluated like this `(repeat' 3) ++ [3]` which leads to an infinite loop.

Whereas in this definition:

```
repeat' :: a -> [a]
repeat' a = a: repeat' a
```

it will be evaluated to WHNF. The `repeat'` will only be evaluated
till the the outermost constructor `:`.

Comment: Thx that answers my problem. What if I move it to the front, it actually works. Is there any difference between this and the right one?

repeat' :: a -> [a]
repeat' a = [a] ++ repeat' a

Comment: @Mystery Yes there is a difference! In your first case, even this will lead to stack overflow `take 3 $ repeat' 5`. But in the case you have mentioned in the comment, it won't produce overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet recurses first and then adds the next element. Because the recursion is infinitely deep, it terminates with a stack overflow before it returns anything. The second snippet returns an element and recurses after that. That means that if you use for example `take 5`, Haskell can generate only five elements.

The reason the first snippet ends with stack overflow is that each of the recursive calls needs to allocate some memory on the stack. Thanks to tail recursion, the second snippet doesn't need to allocate more space with every recursive call.